# How to Split / Separate the Data inside the ArrayList and Store to HTML Table?

Tags: java, html, jsp, hashmap

I'm trying to store the hashMap data into an ArrayList. The problems is when I display the contents inside the arrays list to a html table, it display the whole list in a single cells. I do not know where can I start to solve the problem, whether is I separate/ split the data when I store them or separate/ split them when I need to display at the html table.

> Related Code

```
HashMap hashdata = new HashMap();
List display = hashdata.displayhtml();
```

> displayhtml()

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> hashdata = new hashdata<Integer,List<Integer>>();
List<Object> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();

.....
......
.......
for (int i = 0; i < db.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

        hashdata.put(i,db.getDataAtRow(i));            
    }
    //return tranFIT;
    for (int i = 0; i < db.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

        listOfObjects.add(hashdata.get(i) + "\n");
    }
    return listOfObjects;
```

> html table

```
<table>
<tr>
<%for(int x.....){
     for(int y.....) {%>
    <td>.....<%=display%>.....</td>
   <%}
}%>
</tr>
```

> The Output

[image]

Need some hints and advice please.

Comment: is the way I asked or is my attitude to cause the reputation deduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start of, everything in java is an Object. First you need to create a object. Lets call it PersonInfo and construct this object with the data that you have.

```
public class PersonInfo{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private int telephone; 
    // add setter/getter below
}
```

Lets say you have PersonInfo personInfo
while displaying , you can then use personInfo.getName() and so on.
Not sure if you want to use  `List<PersonInfo> list = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>()` instead of Map.